# Logstash plugin to output to Kafka not working

Tags: plugins, apache-kafka, logstash

I'm trying to send messages from Logstash to Kafka and keep getting the following error:

```
tail -f /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log
[2018-04-18T17:55:33,836][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] 
[Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2018-04-18T17:55:46,095][INFO ][logstash.outputs.kafka   ] Sending batch to Kafka failed. Will retry after a delay. {:batch_size=>1, :failures=>1, :sleep=>0.1}
[2018-04-18T17:55:51,979][INFO ][logstash.outputs.kafka   ] Sending batch to Kafka failed. Will retry after a delay. {:batch_size=>1, :failures=>1, :sleep=>0.1}
[2018-04-18T17:56:46,196][INFO ][logstash.outputs.kafka   ] Sending batch to Kafka failed. Will retry after a delay. {:batch_size=>1, :failures=>1, :sleep=>0.1}]
```

This was working previously, but not now and I'm not sure what changed since the machine was untouched.

I can communicate to Kafka through the console producer on the machine Kafka is running on, as well as the machine Logstash is running on, and from a remote machine out of the VPC, so I don't believe this is a network error. To be sure, I put Logstash on the same machine as Kafka, but I get the same error.

I double checked and made sure that I'm at the latest version of Kafka, Logstash, and the logstash-output-kafka plugin, so I don't think it's a compatibility issue either. I have tried restarting Logstash and the broker to no avail.

Basically, I'm at a loss at how to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My next step in troubleshooting this would be to try running Kafka on your logstash machine, and check if that works. If it does, then there's something up with your Kafka broker's network config, most likely (c.f. https://rmoff.net/2018/01/03/kafka-adminclient-connection-to-node-1-could-not-be-established-broker-may-not-be-available/).

Comment: I am already running kafka and logstash together and logstash cannot send to kafka on that machine either.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. It was a configuration issue in the logstash.conf file: When I changed the kafka output to the machine's local IP address, it works. It doesn't work with the public or private hostname, or the public IP address, it seems. Since I am using a conditional with multiple kafka topics like so:

```
output {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "10.0.0.XX:9092"
    codec => json
    topic_id => "test_topic"
  }
  if [type] == "ping" {
    kafka {
      bootstrap_servers => "10.0.0.XX:9092"
      codec => json
      topic_id => "logstash-ping"
    }
  }
  else if [type] == "snmp" {
    kafka {
      bootstrap_servers => "10.0.0.XX:9092"
      codec => json
      topic_id => "logstash-snmp"
    }
  }
}
```

it won't send to any of them if any one of them is not set right, despite connecting correctly from what I could see in the logstash logs.

For reference, my settings for listeners and advertised.listeners are like so:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9092
```